# Odd CSS/div spacing issue with simple page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following page:
HTML:

```
<div class="spacer">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
</div>

<div class="colorbox">
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div id="message"> XXXX </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;  font-family: Helvetica;}

.box {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height:200px;
    width: 700px;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: #EEEEEE; 
    display: inline-block;
}


.spacer {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height:40px;
}

.colorbox{
 display: inline-block;
 height:120px;
 width:120px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:blue;
}

#message{
    margin:5px;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtv4c10o/5/

I would like to be able to delete the XXX text without moving the line in that border box, but unfortunately that's not working. When I remove it the line moves to look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qtv4c10o/6/

I am eventually going to be updating the XXX text using javascript and don't want the border line to move as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your line goes under the blue square is:

> You gave a fixed width of 700px to the box class.

So if you reduce the size of the window, your line cannot reach 700px: it has to go where there is more space, ie below the box.

Solution: give it a width that can be achieved within the remaining space

The issue was resolved in chat. Here is a working solution:

Let's first wrap `colorbox` and `box` with an `outer` div.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="colorbox"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <div id="message"> XXXX </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `outer` class is so:

```
.outer {
width:100%;/* the whole width available */
height:120px;/* same height as blue square */
display:table;
}
```

We'll give `outerbox` the following property:

```
display:table-cell;
```

and add to box:

```
width: 100%; //the remaining width, actually
margin-top:105px; // blue square height minus height of message
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xzxn4rzf/1/

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I would like the border line to not move at all between the two images and while that comes a lot closer the top line still moves a tiny bit between the two unfortunately. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Also, strange, I am seeing two different things when I look at my jsfiddle in Firefox and Chrome....

Comment: sorry, I am not sure I am following; I thought you wanted the line to stay at the same place, with or without XXX

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That is correct. In Chrome I am seeing that the line moves a little higher when there is the XXXX. (In Firefox the line is below the blue box, which is totally wrong. In Chrome it is, correctly, on the right of the box.) Are you able to replicate that?

Comment: When I reduce the width of the Window in Chrome, it behaves like in Firefox, ie below the box. Just to be sure: you want the line right of the box, and the XXX/text/empty space to be aligned with the bottom of the blue square, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it! And I want the top border to be a little above the bottom of the blue square. Just enough to allow one line of text.

Comment: Thank you! I think I figured out the problem. It is the 'margin' in the message box. When I remove that the problem disappears...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71444/discussion-between-manube-and-garson).